What virtues give a companion-class character a might score?
As the title says: I'm looking for Ars Magica 4 virtues that give a preferably human, companion-class character a Might score.  Preference will be given to virtues with a lower '+' score, higher starting Might, and of the types of Might, the order of preference is Magic, Faerie, Divine and lastly Infernal.
I'm willing to consider virtues from official supplements as well as core rules.
